# Laravel 5.2 - Update routes paths during execution

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.2, I'm trying to update route path during execution because I have multisite running and for cron executions I need to update the routes paths for each site.

I try to just use

```
app('url')->forceRootUrl('https://domain/sitename')
```

but with this method the `asset()` function will use the wrong link.

I try to require the `routes.php` file to rebuild the paths but apparently the changes are not saved.

Any ideas?

Thanks

routes.php :

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => Helpers_SiteTemplate::getSiteRoute($GLOBALS['site_segment'], $GLOBALS['is_cron']),
    'middleware' => ['helpers.siteTemplate'],
], function () {
    Route::get('test', 'Admin\HomeController@debugging');
});
```

- $GLOBALS['site_segment'] and $GLOBALS['is_cron'] will be set only if this is a cron execution on Console/Kernel.php::schedule()
- helpers.siteTemplate will just initialize the proviter.
- Helpers_SiteTemplate::getSiteRoute will just get the site name from the URL or from the param var

this will work normally from the url, in this case : domain.tld/sitename/test, yet from a cron the routes.php will be set the urls without the sitename, then i need to setup the routes again.
I try to `require app_path('Http/routes.php');` from schedule() after set the session vars but the routes are not changed.

Comment: can't you just use a session or config var for this?

Comment: the cron execution class is executed after the boostrap, I do use session vars to set the site name and a middlware in routes.php to fetch the sitename from the url, but when executing a cron I want to execute a run for each site, for this I need to update the route paths each time... but even if I cal Route::get() again the changes are not saved :/

Comment: I think we need to see more code to understand what you are talking about a bit better

Comment: i did update my OP, tell me if more info is needed. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally success in finding a solution for this digging myself in the code, so for future searchers this could be helpful.

If you need to rebuild ROUTES like myself because of cron operations in multisite laravel or other reason i finally did it with this code :

```
// Get the router facade from anyware
$router = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::getFacadeRoot();
// Clear the current routes by setting a empty route collection
$routes = new \Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection;
$router->setRoutes($routes);

// Get the route service provider
$routeserviceprovider = new \App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider(app());
// Call the map function from the provider, this will remap all routes from the app\Http\routes.php
app()->call([$routeserviceprovider, 'map']);
```

if i can help with further info do contact me.

thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is outdated, for Laravel 5.7:

```
    $router = app('router');
    // Clear the current routes by setting a empty route collection
    $routes = new \Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection;
    $router->setRoutes($routes);
    // Get the route service provider
    $routeserviceprovider = app()->getProvider(RouteServiceProvider::class);
    // Call the map function from the provider, this will remap all routes from the app\Http\routes.php
    app()->call([$routeserviceprovider, 'map']);
    $routes = Route::getRoutes();
    $routes->refreshNameLookups();
    $routes->refreshActionLookups();
    $router->setRoutes($routes);
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated my project to **Laravel 8.33** and after many hours of testing this worked for me :

```
// clear routes
$router = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::getFacadeRoot();
$routes = new \Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection;
$router->setRoutes($routes);

// load routes
Route::middleware('web')
    ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers')
    ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```